# how to use xpath in camel-context.xml to check if a particular node is exist or not

Tags: xpath, apache-camel, xmlnode

I am trying to develop a content-based routing camel application. This application will look at the folder src/data to see if there is a SOAP request file that has node `<e2d:getOrderDetaiRequest>`, then that file will be copy into target/message, otherwise the file will be copy to target/other.

**Do you know how to use xpath(or any other tools ) to check that condition (i prefer using camel-context.xml file)?**

Here is my camel-context

```
<route>
        <from uri="file://c:/src/data?noop=true"/>
        <choice>
           <when>
            <xpath>**???????????????????????????**</xpath>
                <to uri="file://c:/target/message"/>
           </when>
           <otherwise>
            <to uri="file://c:/target/other"/>
           </otherwise>
        </choice>
    </route>
```

And here is the sample of 2 different SOAP requests

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:e2d="http://www.abc.com/Abc11WS">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <e2d:getOrderDetailRequest>
         <actionCode>1234</actionCode>
      </..>
   </...></...>
```

And

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:lsr="http://www.abc.com/Abc22WS">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <lsr:getProductDetailsRequest>
           <productId>12345</...>
     </...></...></...>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using xpath and your xml has namespaces, such as your SOAP message, then you must use namespaces in the xpath expression as well.

There is some details at the Camel docmentation at: http://camel.apache.org/xpath

By using the XML DSL in Camel you can declare the namespace in the XML tag directly such as in the camelContext etc.

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring" e2d="http://www.abc.com/Abc11WS">
   ...
   <when>
     <xpath>/e2d:getOrderDetailRequest</xpath>
       ...
```

But mind that XPaths can be a bit tricky to get working correctly. And that is why we added the logNamespaces in Camel 2.10. See details in the bottom of the this page: http://camel.apache.org/xpath

Comment: Thanks Ibsen. I declared e2d="http://www.abc.com/Abc11WS" in CamelContext tag but the xml file got error: cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'e2d' is not allowed to appear in element 'camelContext'.

Comment: You need to add a declaration to this namespace in the very top, eg there is some for Camel etc. You need the same for your namespace as well. eg its standard xml/namespace stuff.

Comment: so in the beans tag: <beans xmlns=".." xmlns:camel=".."      xmlns:cxf=".." xmlns:xsi=".."      xmlns:e2d="http://www.abc.com/Abc11WS"
xsi:schemaLocation="... http://www.abc.com/Abc11WS file://c:/.../etc/entertainment/abc11ws_schema1.xsd">. But the error is still there. Sorry, i am not good in those xml/qualified name.

Comment: See the xpath documentation at Camel, the section titled _Using XML configuration_. Notice the foo namespace.

Comment: Thanks Ibsen. I did followed the document. The XML is fine now. But when i ran the application. It didn't work as i expect. It looks like the condition is always get false value. here is the log file that i got: "org.apache.camel.camel-core - 2.6.0 | #0 - XPath: /e2d:getOrderDetailRequest matches: false for: Exchange[Message: [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]]
 Endpoint[file://c:/target] Exchange[Message: [Body is instance of java.io.InputStream]]
 Wrote [c:\target\other\xxxxxxxx] to [Endpoint[file://c:/target/other]]"

Comment: Ah you may have to do <xpath>//e2d:getOrderDetailRequest</xpath> to indicate to xpath to search the entire tree. I told you XPath expressions is a pain in the .... There may be some xpath validation tools you can try out to get it working first.

Comment: Wow, Claus. You are my savior. :-). It is working now. Again, thanks for your patience to answer all my questions.

Comment: Yes good. In the doc it's not always easy to catch all the subtleties of the samples. I just thought the xpath can guess the NS but it is not the case. With the NS declaration in the camel-context it works fine.