# Camel retrieving xml tag name using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, apache-camel

I'm not able to get the xpath expression to work.  I'm using Camel 2.15.1.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've tried the following

```
<xpath>name(//*[1])='PPR_PC2'</xpath>
<xpath>name("//*[local-name()='PPR_PC2')</xpath>
<xpath>//PPR_PC2</xpath>
```

My xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PPR_PC2 xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
   <MSH>
      <MSH.1>|</MSH.1>
      ...
      ...
    </MSH>
    ...
    ...
</PPR_PC2>
```

My Camel route

```
<route id="_route_1">
    <from uri="activemq:queue:myQIN"/>

    <doTry>
        <choice>
            <when>
                // This path works without having namespace 
                <xpath>name(//*[1])='PPR_PC2'</xpath>
                <to uri="xslt:transform/stylesheet.xsl"/>
                <to uri="..."/>
            </when>
            <otherwise> ... </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <doCatch> ... </doCatch>
    </doTry>
</route>
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
[thread #1 - JmsConsumer[myQIN]] EndpointMessageListener
    WARN  Execution of JMS message listener failed. 
    Caused by: [org.apache.camel.builder.xml.InvalidXPathExpression - Invalid xpath: name(//*[1])='PPR_PC2'. 
    Reason: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: 
    A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of name() (<PPR_PC2/>, <MSH/>, ...) ]
org.apache.camel.builder.xml.InvalidXPathExpression: 
    Invalid xpath: name(//*[1])='PPR_PC2'. 
    Reason: javax.xml.xpath.XPathExpressionException: net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: 
    A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of name() (<PPR_PC2/>, <MSH/>, ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message

A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of name()

suggests that when you wrote

```
name(//*[1])
```

(which selects every element that is the first child of its parent)

you probably meant

```
name((//*)[1])
```

(which selects the first element in the document)

though that would give you exactly the same as

```
name(/*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the namespace and use it. Note the `xmlns` below.

```
<route id="_route_1" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v2xml">
    <from uri="activemq:queue:myQIN"/>

    <doTry>
        <choice>
            <when>
                <xpath>/hl7:PPR_PC2</xpath>
                <to uri="xslt:transform/stylesheet.xsl"/>
                <to uri="..."/>
            </when>
            <otherwise> ... </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <doCatch> ... </doCatch>
    </doTry>
</route>
```

You can pick any prefix you like, but you have to pick a prefix in order to be able to declare and use a namespace. I chose `hl7` for the example.

Declare the namespace higher up in your XML file to be able to use it in multiple places.

Also read [how to use xpath in camel-context.xml to check if a particular node is exist or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9626285/18771)

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```
Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("cus","http://...");

ns.xpath("//MSH.1/text()", java.lang.String.class)
```